# Медленно шифруются файлы алгоритмом AES

Tags: c#, шифрование, aes

Я тут новенький)

У меня очень медленно шифруются файлы по определённым дискам

[Метод взял с этого форума](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1780588.html)

---

Использую следующий алгоритм шифрования:

```
public byte[] AES_Encrypt(string inputFile, string password)
{
   byte[] result = null; byte[] salt = new byte[12];
   try
   {
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
      byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFile);
      using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
      using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
      {
         rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
         rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
         var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(bytes, salt, 1000);
         rijndaelManaged.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
         rijndaelManaged.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
         rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
         using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
         {
            cryptoStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
         }
         result = memoryStream.ToArray();
       }
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex) { File.AppendAllText("AES_Enc.txt", ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.ToString()); }
    catch (IOException ex) { File.AppendAllText("AES_Enc_IO.txt", ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.ToString()); }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
    return result;
}
```

Использую так:

```
string[] drives = {"E:", "D:", }; 
foreach (string drv in drives)
{
    IEnumerable<string> MyFiles = SafeEnumerateFiles(drv, new[]{"*.txt"}, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string fileName in MyFiles)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, AES_Encrypt(fileName, password));
    }    
}
```

Но файлы очень медленно шифруются, как будто установлен `Thread.Sleep(3000);` Подскажите как можно ускорить процесс обработки?

Может какой-то недостаток в реализация метода AES_Encrypt ?

Хочу сделать себе простенькую реализацию по защите данных от посторонних глаз ( шифруя их )

Comment: можешь шифровать файлы в несколько потоков (`Thread`/`Task`). + мне кажется нужно использовать потоки `Stream` не загружая весь файл в память (но не знаю как это влияет на производительность)

Comment: @dgzargo, А это как в несколько потоков? Я не представляю как это будет реализовано ))

Comment: Ну во-первых, шифрование само по себе вещь небыстрая, во-вторых, вполне возможно что свои тормоза добавляют медленные винчестеры. Вы шифруете много мелких файлов? Один крупный? Какая скорость получается в Мбит/с? Я бы зашифровал простым XOR (степень защиты: нулевая) и посмотрел, насколько быстрее получится. А то может оказаться так, что у вас разницы-то и не будет. Вопрос не очень подходит для стека, так как плохо сформулирован. Медленно - это весьма суьбьективная категория.

Comment: Так ваш код ничего не шифрует. Он просто создает зашифрованный массив байт в памяти и ничего с ним не делает.

Comment: @AK, Файлов много и они разного размера, нет не один крупный ( они разного размера ) На счёт скорости не знаю, а как это в Мбит/c считать? Oo У меня вот как работает шифруется один файл, проходит секунды 3-4 затем следующий и.т.д

Comment: @Faust8 с такой большой задержкой 3-4 сек, вы можете в режиме отладки посмотреть, какая именно строка тормозит

Comment: Ну, вы можете во-первых взять профилировщик и посмотреть, на чём именно тормозит ваш код - и это будет самое лучшее, что можно сделать. Во-вторых, вы можете суммировать длины каждого файла (посчитав тем самым количество байт) и отдельно замерить через Stopwatch время выполнения скрипта.

Comment: То есть с самим алгоритмом всё нормально? Это не из-за него так медленно шифруются файлы? Я конечно посмотрю что по тестам.

Comment: @Faust8 код конечно немного неоптимальный, но это не критично. Лучше посмотрите какая конкретно строка тормозит.

Comment: @Zergatul, Приму во внимание что можно дополнить/изменить)

Comment: @Faust8 не нужно каждый раз создавать `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, так как пароль и IV одинаковые. их можно посчитать один раз перед процессингом файлов. зачем писать в `MemoryStream`, конвертировать в массив, а потом писать в файл, если можно сразу писать в `FileStream`?

Comment: @Zergatul, А можно как ответ, или отдельно создать тему? Было бы не плохо увидеть готовый вариант

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в 2 foreach и File.WriteAllBytes. Вам необходимо придумать другой метод нахождения и считывания ваших файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что такая работа с 1 файлом это самый оптимальный способ. Можно еще попробовать указать вручную последним параметром размер буффера:

```
static void AESProcess(string filename, byte[] key, byte[] iv, bool encrypt)
{
    // открываем 2 потока с 1 файлом, с одного читаем, в другой пишем
    using (var fsRead = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var fsWrite = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsWrite, encrypt ? aes.CreateEncryptor() : aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            fsRead.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            // после дешифрования размер файла уменьшается
            // нам нужно вручную установить длину 
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            fsWrite.SetLength(fsWrite.Position);
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] key, iv;
    using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("qwerty", new byte[12], 1000))
    {
        key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
        iv = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(16);
    }

    // тут ваш foreach
    AESProcess("test.txt", key, iv, true);
}
```

Comment: Скажите Rfc2898DeriveBytes реализует idisposable требуется ли для него вызов using() ?

Comment: Да, реализует. По хорошему нужно вызывать.

Comment: Могу поинтересоваться а как проверить что файл уже был зашифрован данным алгоритмом?

Comment: @Faust8 откройте его в чем либо, увидите внутри мусор. или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Faust8 в текущем варианте никак, нужно помечать как-то файл, менять имя, или дописывать что-то внутри

Comment: Скажи пожалуйста, а нужно ли 32 байта и 16 делить на 8 ? так: `GetBytes(32 / 8)` и `GetBytes(16 / 8)` ?

Comment: @Faust8 не нужно, длина ключа 256 бит, это 32 байта.